How do I connect joystick to Windows 2008 machine?
I have a machine running Windows 2008 x64 and tried connecting a Logitech Extreme 3D Pro joystick. While the device appears in "Devices and Printers" in the Control Panel, I can't calibrate it or use all its features. When I select "Settings" from the joystick's pop-up menu, nothing happens.
In Device Manager, the joystick is listed, but I can't configure or calibrate it there either. The driver shown is the standard Microsoft driver (dated 21.06.2006, version 6.1.7601.24386). Attempts to update the driver result in a message stating that the current driver is the most suitable one.
When I try using the joystick in a game, it is partially recognized, but not all features work. Only three of the four axes are functional (the throttle is not detected), and most buttons are unresponsive.
From my understanding, there might be additional driver components or some special stuff for gaming devices, included in Windows 7 that are missing in Windows 2008. I have access to a Windows 7 machine and could transfer the necessary components if I knew what to look for.
Perhaps, some registry tweaks also needed.
Could anyone guide me on which components are required?

On the logitech website, you can go to support, search for the Extreme 3D Pro and under downloads you will find the Logitech Gaming Software which can be used to configure your device. Have you tried this ?

Windows Server 2008 is an OS for servers. It is optimized to run more stable and as such certain features that workstations would need have been removed partially or entirely. I'm fairly sure that this is the problem you're having. You should not use a server OS to game on. Host a gaming server, sure, but you don't need a joystick for that.

@Silbee Yes I tried. It did not help. Nothing changes after installing it.

There were missing files

Windows\System32\joy.cpl
Windows\System32\en-US\joy.cpl.mui
Windows\SysWOW64\joy.cpl
Windows\SysWOW64\en-US\joy.cpl.mui

These files can be taken from respective directories from Windows 7 or Vista.
A zip archive including these files along with a script for installing them (just copying, in fact) is available at https://www.windowsworkstation.com/win2008r2/game-controllers/
After I placed these files in the appropriate directories, everything worked fine.
